# Changing imageurl programmatically not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, imageurl

I need to change an image after it was uploaded. I don't want to bind. 
The code I use after image uploading and storing image path in database is:

```
   imgUser.ImageUrl = "UserPics/" & ("image1") & ".jpg"
```

`image1` is the name of the field in the SQL database where the image path is stored, but it is not working.

In the html part, the imageurl is:

```
   <asp:Image ID="imgUser" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="150px" ImageUrl="/UserPics/Thumb1/noimage.jpg"/>
```

`noimage.jpg` is the defalut image to show.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: if you were to use a program like firebug and inspect the generated element, what shows up? Is the src attribute correct?

Comment: What does `"UserPics/" & ("image1") & ".jpg"` look like? Is it really physically available in that folder? Is *noimage.jpg* displaying correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
imgUser.ImageUrl = "~/UserPics/" & ("image1") & ".jpg"
```

or use [`Server.MapPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) to get the absolute URL of the web server. Your original post translates to a local path instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder `UserPics` is at root of your web-app then the path of image file should be:

```
string filename="sample.jpg"; // you may retrieve it from the database
imgUser.ImageUrl = "~/UserPics/" &  filename
```